# Kenwood TS-440SAT Change VFO Resolution?

Tags: diy, kenwood

When I turn the VFO on my Kenwood TS-440 it changes the frequency in 10Hz steps.  One full rotation changes it by 1kHz.  There is a modification (by cutting a diode lead) to change the frequency DISPLAY resolution but not the tuning resolution.

I am hoping someone has a way to change the VFO by 10x.  So that it moves in 100Hz steps.

I would also be content with 1kHz steps if I can then disable the mod once I got close to the desired frequency.  I was thinking an external switch connected to the unused connector (ACC3 is a RCA connector) on the back of the rig would be perfect so no other case modification is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the knob a good flick in the direction you want to go. The radio automatically switches to 1kHz tuning when the knob is moving at a fast pace.

[Manual page 8, paragraph 22](http://inform3.kenwoodusa.com/Manuals/TS-440.pdf)